# Capture more than one line of text

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I have `txt` file where every news start with

```
* This is new title *
this is the body 
thid is the body
....
* This is another title *
```

User select title he wants from `ListBox` (with double click). I want my program to check the file again and select the text between the two titles (body of the selected news).

This is my current function, but only thing it do is to add the title from `ListBox` to `TextBox` (where new body should be).

Thanks for any help.

```
private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string text = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    string tempLineValue;
    string txtFile = path.Text; //path is TextBox with file path
    Regex regex = new Regex(@text + "(.*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

    using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(txtFile))
    {
        while (null != (tempLineValue = inputReader.ReadLine()))
        {
            if (regex.Match(tempLineValue).Success)
            {
                myList.Add((regex.Match(tempLineValue)).Value);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        textBox.Text = myList.ElementAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match Regex across newlines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782258/match-regex-across-newlines)

Comment: Could always find the line equal to the title you want (since you know exactly what it should be) and add all following lines until you reach another title line, then stop.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Singleline didn't solve the problem. May te problem be in regex?

Comment: @HC1122 "Didn't solve the problem". Are you able to describe what it DID do? Did it match nothing? Did it match everything from the selected title to the end of the file? Did it do something else entirely?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Result is still the same as before, when I didn't have Signeline option. So it displayed same title again, not the body of the news.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute -- you're reading the file line by line. Right, you don't want a multiline match. You want to read the file and discard each line *until* you get a title match. When that happens, set a bool flag variable, `foundStory`. In the loop, if `foundStory` is true, check to see if the line is a title (*any* title). If it's a title, it's the NEXT title -- so you have the whole story. Break out of the loop. If it's not the next title yet, then it's the next line of the current story. Append the line to  a string variable `storyText`.

Comment: Once you're done with the loop, `storyText` is the text of the story, do whatever with it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Am pretty new at C# and regex, but gonna understand what you wrote and try your solution.

Comment: IMO you can do it faster and easy by : 1) reading the whole file with "ReadToEnd" method. 2) use string.split('*') on the result, this will produce an array of string where you have in position "i" a title and in "i+1" your content 3) convert your array into list of object with 2 properties "title" and "content" and set this list as the "items" parameter on your ListBox with "displayMember" set to "title". 4) on selectedItemChanged event in your listBox just set textBox.text = selectedItem.Content

Answer (score 1):

You want to get news body based on the title from a file. It's not possible by reading the file line by line. You have to read full file. After that you can try Regex to search and get your news body. I write a [Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/t4KDRJ/1) to search your news body based on title. Also I tested it C#, it's working for me. You can try below code.

CODE:

```
string text = " This is new title ";
string txtFile = @"D:\New Text Document.txt"; //path is TextBox with file path
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*" + text + @"\*(\t|\n|\r|\s)+(.*)(\t|\n|\r|\s)+(.*)(\t|\n|\r)+\*", RegexOptions.Multiline);

using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(txtFile))
{
    string txt = inputReader.ReadToEnd();
    Match match = regex.Match(txt);
    richTextBox1.Text = match.Value.Replace("*" + text + "*", "").Replace("*", "");
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string text = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string tempLineValue;
    string txtFile = path.Text; //path is TextBox with file path

    string title = null;
    using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(txtFile))
    {
        while (null != (tempLineValue = inputReader.ReadLine()))
        {
            if (tempLineValue.StartsWith("*"))
                title = tempLineValue.Substring(2, tempLineValue.Length - 4).Trim();
            else if (text == title)
                textBox.Text += tempLineValue + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

It should work provided that the text (listBox.SelectedItem) variable has a value of for example "This is new title" without the *'s.

Comment: Looks like nothing happens when I double click on selected line, also should be done with Regex, not substrings.

Comment: Debug the code to find out why then. Or provide a full reproducible sample of your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve